# how to get data attribute in ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to get data-id from anchor tag on click using ajax but it returns me undefined
following is my code

```php
$image_html .= '<a class="float-left " onclick="modal()" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-id="'.$file->id.'" href="#MyModal" title="'.$file->alt_text.'"><div class="img-responsive" style="margin:10px;  border: solid darkslategrey ;">
<img src="'.url('assets/uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/images/media_thumb_'.$file->title).'" alt="'.$file->alt_text.'" width="120">
</div></a>   ';
```

on clicking above anchor tag modal function called also this anchor tag is coming from rendering the html in another ajax call

```js
function modal()
{
    var AJAX_URL = {!! json_encode(url('medialibrary/modal')) !!}

    var dataId = $(this).data("id");

    console.log(dataId);
    $.ajax({
        url: AJAX_URL,
        method: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "data_id" : dataId ,
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $(".modal-body").empty();
            $(".modal-body-1").empty();
            $(".modal-body-2").empty();
            $(".modal-body").append(result.Record1);
            $(".modal-body-1").append(result.Record2);
            $(".modal-body-2").append(result.Record3);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) is not in scope.

Try

```
const dataId = $("[href='#MyModal']").data("id");
```

or pass it:

```
onclick="modal(this)"
```

and use

```
function modal(lnk) {
  const dataId = lnk.dataset.id;
```

A better way is addressing all the modal links - remove the onclick and do :

```
const AJAX_URL = {!! json_encode(url('medialibrary/modal')) !!}
$("[data-toggle=modal]").on("click",function(e) {
  const dataId = $(this).data("id");
.....
```

you MAY want to use `e.preventDefault()` but since it is a modal toggle I am not sure

Comment: this anchor tag is in foreach loop and have multiple anchors and their respective id's

Comment: So use the second example

Comment: If you use your function onclick on which is reached element then scope is the same, meaning you should access $(this) via your function "modal", I think there is a other problem, first, tyr to use console.log($(this) and check which element showing, if it is "a" element thn you should look browseer dev tools and your code generates data-id value

Comment: @TalhaArif Please see the last example which does away with the onclick

Comment: @mplungjan for sure .. and thanks alot once again :)